# React Native Text components renders with superfluous lines on iPhone Plus

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm getting stuck with undesired grey lines on the top and/or right of every Text component when run on an iPhone Plus. The bug does not reproduce on the simulator, only on device. The seems to be a bug within React Native (I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10682)) but I'm posting here for any extra insight and workarounds as well.

[image: Image of superfluous lines]

When inspecting the Text components, any component that has a non-integer width or height will show a line like this. A non-integer width adds a border to the right, a non-integer height adds a border to the top.

If I explicitly set a height for each Text component to an integer value I can prevent the top borders, but the width of the Text depends on the length of it content which I cannot control. In the attached image the texts that say "Commentary | 24" and "Tanakh | 2" have the same structure/styling -- but the difference in text length causes one to have a border right and the other not.

This seems related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2018

Any suggestions for workarounds are greatly appreciated as well. This issue is ugly and pervasive.

The bug is present in this app: https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-iOS as of 11/1/2016.

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.35.0
- Platform: iOS on devices with PixelDensity 3, does not reproduce on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem too. I did your suggestion by adding width and height to Text, but it doesn't really help well. Then I followed the instruction from the related issue that you wrote: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2018

I enabled back the LaunchScreen, then the problem gone.

Comment: I found the same after reading more carefully through the first related issue. Enable the LaunchScreen fixed the problem. So it seems like this is still an outstanding but in React Native when LaunchScreen is disabled, but at least there is a way forward.